# "unexpected EOF" when debugging with GDB in eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, bash, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Since yesterday, I have an issue with the Debug mode of Eclipse Oxygen CDT (the problem does not occur in Run mode), that seems related to the length of the arguments of the program, transmitted to GDB.
I am under Ubuntu 17.04, x64 (in VirtualBox)

To reproduce it:

1. create a simple project (like a `Hello World`)
2. Create a debug configuration and enter at least (on my machine) 3966 characters
3. Launch Debug

Then Eclipse gives me the following pop-up

[image]

And in the console I can see:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching "'"
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I've found that, in Debug mode, eclipse encloses arguments with simple quotes; so the problem seems to be a too long string argument. `getconf ARG_MAX` gives me `2097152`

Comment: Double check the quotes.  You might have an unquoted one in there.

Comment: It's obviously the first check I did. As arguments for this test, I juste paste a repeated sequence of 1234567890, with no quotes at all.